# Join multiple columns horizontally into one column with ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

Sheet:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e |
| f | g | h | i | j |
| k | l | m | n | o |

Currently to join the values horizontally of the columns, I do like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="","",A1:A&B1:B&C1:C&D1:D&E1:E))
```

Output:

| F |
| --- |
| abcde |
| fghij |
| klmno |

But now I came across the need to join the values of 100 columns, manually it's a huge formula, so I'm looking for a way to set the range to `A1:CV`, but `JOIN` and `CONCATENATE` don't support this type of multicolumn range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:E);;9^9))
```

if you dont need extra spaces remove them like:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:E);;9^9)); " "; ))
```

if columns contain words with spaces and you want to keep only those use:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(A:E; " "; "×"));;9^9)); " "; ); "×"; " "))
```